# Problems using VIewHolder fun and variable

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, data-binding, android-viewholder, dagger-hilt

I'm having trouble binding my ViewHolder, and I've got two warning that I believe are related. I am trying to use Hilt to create a clickable ViewHolder, so in my SessionAdapter I am using an inner class to bind my SessionViewHolder to my RecyclerView.

First, I am struggling to understand what to return for the *inner class SessionViewHolder fun bind(session: Session) { ...}*. Android Studio is telling me function "bind" is never used, but I thought I used it in my onBindViewHolder?

Secondly, in my override *onBindViewHolder* I don't understand how I should use *val session*?

@AndroidEntryPoint

class SessionFragment : Fragment() {

```
var adapter: SessionAdapter = SessionAdapter()

private val sessionAdapter = SessionListAdapter(this::onSessionClicked)


private fun onSessionClicked(session: Session): Session {
    return(session)

}

class SessionAdapter {
    fun setOnClickListener() {
        return(addSessionToItinerary())
    }

    private fun addSessionToItinerary() {
        return addSessionToItinerary()
    }


}


class SessionListAdapter(
    private val onSessionCLicked:  (Session) -> Unit,
) : ListAdapter<Session, SessionListAdapter.SessionViewHolder>(SessionItemCallback) {

    inner class SessionViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind() {
            val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(0)

            fun bind(session: Session) {
                textView.text = session.title
                itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    onSessionCLicked(session)
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SessionViewHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_session_list, parent, false)

        return SessionViewHolder(itemView)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SessionViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val session = getItem(position)
        holder.bind()

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for you help. I have gotten myself confused with the recurrence of bind and session throughout my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

See here in this code, you have defined two `bind` functions, but one is nested inside the other so it is unusable:

```
    fun bind() {
        val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(0)

        fun bind(session: Session) {
            textView.text = session.title
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onSessionCLicked(session)
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
        }
    }
```

The outer `bind()` function is the one you are calling, and it doesn't make sense to bind nothing. This function gets a reference to a TextView, and it creates a function that is never used.

Another problem is that you are passing 0 to `findViewById`. There is never going to be a view with an ID of 0. You need to pass `R.id.whateverYourTextViewIsNamedInYourXml`.

Side note, `return@onClickListener` is unnecessary. If a function doesn't return anything, putting a return statement on the last line doesn't do anything.

To make it work, you should replace the above code with something like this, but replace the name of the text view with whatever ID you assigned it in your XML:

```
    fun bind(session: Session) {
        val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTextView)
        textView.text = session.title
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onSessionCLicked(session)
        }
    }
```

and then pass the `session` to this function when you call it.

Side note, your SessionAdapter class doesn't make any sense at all, but you're not using it for anything anyway. I would delete that.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This immediately solved my problem.  I am going to build out my SessionAdapter class to post favorited sessions to a second fragment with a list.  I am thinking I'll need to use a repository to accomplish this.  

I apologize if this is off topic or if asking an unrelated follow-up question in the comments is not allowed on Stack, but do you think I'm on the right track with thinking I will have to use a repository?

Comment: Repository is a very loose term that can mean a database, a file or set of files, some cloud API, even just a class storing some temporary objects in RAM, etc. It just means a place that stores data in an organized way. I don't know what a *session* is in the context of your app, so I don't know if it's something you need to write to disk or only need for the duration of a session of your app running.

Comment: Session is something that I think I'll need to write to disk, because I'd like it to exist after the app is closed.  I apologize for the confusing name I gave to my data class *session*.  As I was working, I also realized how that might get confusing in regard to lifecycle.

I have a database *SessionDatabase* and a dao *SessionDao* for my data class *Session*, but I don't think I'll be able to reuse the *SessionDatabase* to hold the Sessions I'd like to save.